# Returning the sum of some value in a list

Tags: python, function, loops

**Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers
like, summer_69([1, 3, 5]) = 9 // summer_69([1,2,3,6,4,5,5,7,9,1,2,3]) = 12 // summer_69([1,2,3,6,9]) = 6...I tried but the code below doesn't show any output, what's the problem**

```
def summer_69(arr):
  sums = 0
  sums2 = 0
  flag = False
      for nums in arr:
          while nums != 6:
              sums = sums + nums
              if nums == 6:
                  flag = True
                  break
      if flag == True:
          for nums1 in arr[::-1]:
              while nums1 != 9:
                  sums2 += nums1
      return sums2 + sums

result = summer_69([1, 3, 5])
print(result)
```

Comment: Will you give some test cases to better understanding your problem?

Comment: It looks like your "while nums != 6:" loop is running infity time.

Comment: Both your while loops are infinite loops, because you don't do anything inside the loop that will affect the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following -

```
def summer_69(arr, curr_sum=0):
    if 6 not in arr:
        return curr_sum + sum(arr)
    six_index = arr.index(6)
    nine_index = arr.index(9, six_index)
    curr_sum += sum(arr[:six_index])
    return summer_69(arr[nine_index+1:], curr_sum)
```

If there is no `6` in the list - return the sum of the list. Otherwise, split the list into 3 parts - before the `6`, between `6` and `9` and after the `9`. Then sum the first part (before `6`) using `sum`, ignore the middle part (between `6` and `9`) and follow the summation logic for the last part (after the `9`) by recalling this method.